# Joomla 3.4.4 multilanguage urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, seo, joomla3.0

This get me crazy i spent the last day search for solution for this issue but until no i can't find any my problem is as follow 
i have this site http://www.yadonia.com/ that have only one language (English) 
the client need to add Arabic language to the site as a normal Joomla (i did that about 100 time for other sites on the same server) i install the new language and activate all the required plugin and add default menu for each language and configure the Language Filter to hide the default Language Code from the url but when i go to the site to test the installation i notice that the url look like 
http://www.yadonia.com/?lang=en or http://www.yadonia.com/?lang=ar
and event if i try to but http://www.yadonia.com/en it's redirect me to http://www.yadonia.com/?lang=en

i can't leave the site with this issue so i stopped the  plugins and download the site to my local server and run i and it work with no problem i didn't change any code and it's work as i want so the url for English is http://www.yadonia.com/
and for Arabic is http://www.yadonia.com/ar

Note: i have about 20 site with 2 language on the same server and all of them is work with no problem

any idea how to solve the problem on the online server or at least where should i start search

==========
now i'm 100% sure that it;s host problem (not server) just this host
coz i copy all the database and the folders to new host on the same server and it's work with no problem

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a `.htaccess` file issue. Rename the file to `_.htaccess` and try.

One last option: try to disable `mod_sec` for this domain in-order to test if its related. If related, check the logs to see which `mod_sec` rule.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure that the problem occurs because you are not working properly the friendly url.

Activate them using the documentation of Joomla.

https://docs.joomla.org/Enabling_Search_Engine_Friendly_(SEF)_URLs

When you go to "Extensions->language->language and content" and you click on "URL Language Code" You can see a picture like this ...
[image]

**You have to focus your efforts on SEF enabled, so the suffix is correct.**

Comment: as i mention before i have about 20 site with multi language on the same server with no issue the work as expected
any way go throw each step in the page you mention and all is set to what Joomla recommend

Comment: now i'm 100% sure that it;s host problem (not server) just this host
coz i copy all the database and the folders to new host on the same server and it's work with no problem